# Atom package linter-flake8 not showing output

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8

I have installed linter-flake8 with Atom on MacOSX. Atom automatically installed linter. My problem is that the package doesn't detect any errors with python scripts. The strange thing is that if I run flake8 from the command line, it does detect multiple errors and specifies in which file the errors occured.

Here is a screenshot:

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/34/1472320581-capture-d-ecran-2016-08-27-a-19-55-57.png

Comment: The typical problem with using atom linter packages with MacOSX is that MacOSX sometimes has issues with your shell environment propagating into Atom. Because of that, your path to the flake8 executable might need to be specified in the `linter-flake8` settings.

Comment: Okay, I have change the path it seems to work on new file. But it wont work on old .py files that I have written a while ago... Any idea why ? Also he keep getting me an error on new file about the docstring I dont know why... Here are some screenshot : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/34/1472394847-capture-d-ecran-2016-08-28-a-16-33-39.png
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/34/1472394847-capture-d-ecran-2016-08-28-a-16-33-44.png

Comment: What is flake8 outputting for that file?

Comment: Here is a screenshot in atom : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/34/1472398327-capture-d-ecran-2016-08-28-a-17-31-40.png and the output using flake8 on the same file : http://pastebin.com/t8PRNdz1

Comment: You should probably file an issue on their github.

Comment: I have already but their github is not very active... Do you think it can be linked to the fact that I use an alternative shell ? I'm currently on fish

Comment: Ping ArcaneMagus (Landon Abney) in the issue and request a new maintainer for the project.

Comment: Okay thanks I have pinged him. What do you mean by requesting a new maintainer ?

Answer (score 0):

I've notices several Flake8 plugins don't support reading from stdin priperly since `flake8 >= 3`. The flake8 Atom package basically runs `cat $FILENAME | flake8 -`. Try running that command from the terminal and report differences in output to the relevant plugin.

Comment: Your command run indefinitly but the output of "flake8" is : http://pastebin.com/VC2RLXSy